# Knockout and Semantic UI Multi Select Dropdown with pre-selected values with a collection inside a model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-core-mvc, semantic-ui

Using Knockout and Semantic UI.
I'm trying to figure out how to get the values selected for my multi select dropdown.  The first dropdown works with just single values, but the multi select one dosent.  I have an observable array inside another collection:

```
 <tbody id="tbodyelement" data-bind="foreach: groupUserCollection">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="ui selection dropdown fluid">
                        <input type="hidden" name="groupDD" data-bind="value: group.name">
                        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                        <div class="default text">Select Group</div>
                        <div class="menu" data-bind="foreach: $parent.groupCollection">
                            <div class="item" data-bind="text: $data.name(), attr: {'data-value': $data.id()}"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>

                        <div class="ui multiple selection dropdown long-width" id="multi-select">
                            <div data-bind="foreach: user">
                                <input type="hidden" name="userDD" data-bind="value: firstLastName"> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="default text">Select User</div>
                            <div class="menu" data-bind="foreach: $parent.userCollection">
                                <div class="item" data-bind="text: $data.firstLastName(), attr: {'data-value': $data.id()}"></div>
                            </div>
                            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </td>


            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I have one model groupuser that has a group model in it and a collection of roles.

```
var groupUser = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.group = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.group),
        self.user = ko.observableArray([]),         
        self.id = ko.observable(data.id),
        self.group.subscribe = function () {
            showButtons();
        },
        self.user.subscribe = function () {
          //  self.user.push(data.user);
            showButtons();
        }

};
 var group = function (data) {
    var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable(data.id),
        self.name = ko.observable(data.name),
        self.project = ko.observable(data.project),
        self.projectId = ko.observable(data.projectId),
        self.role = ko.observable(data.role),
        self.roleId = ko.observable(data.roleId)                
};
    var user = function (data) {
    var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable(data.id),
        self.accountId = ko.observable(data.accountId),
        self.email = ko.observable(data.email),
        self.firstName = ko.observable(data.firstName),
        self.lastName = ko.observable(data.lastName),
            self.firstLastName = ko.pureComputed({
             read: function()
            {
                return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
            }
            ,
            write: function(value)
            {
                var lastSpacePos = value.lastIndexOf(" ");
                if (lastSpacePos > 0) { 
                    self.firstName(value.substring(0, lastSpacePos)); 
                    self.lastName(value.substring(lastSpacePos + 1)); 
                }
                console.log("firstname: " + self.firstName());
            }

        }),

};

  groupViewModel = {
    groupUserCollection: ko.observableArray(),
    userCollection: ko.observableArray(),
    groupCollection: ko.observableArray()
 }
```

I add the data using this function:

```
$(data).each(function (index, element) {

                var newGroup = new group({
                    id: element.group.id,
                    name: element.group.name,
                    project: element.group.project,
                    projectId: element.group.projectId,
                    role: element.group.role,
                    roleId: element.group.roleId       
                });
                newGroup.id.subscribe(
                    function () {
                        newGroupUser.showButtons();
                    }
                );
                newGroup.name.subscribe(
                    function () {
                        newGroupUser.showButtons();
                    }
                );


                var newGroupUser = new groupUser({
                    group: newGroup,
                    id: element.id,

                });

                ko.utils.arrayForEach(element.user, function (data) {
                    var newUser = new user({
                        id: data.id,
                        accountId: data.accountId,
                        email: data.email,
                        firstName: data.firstName,
                        lastName: data.lastName,
                    });

                    newUser.id.subscribe(
                        function () {
                            newGroupUser.showButtons();
                        }
                    );
                    newUser.firstName.subscribe(
                        function () {
                            newGroupUser.showButtons();
                        }
                    );
                    newUser.lastName.subscribe(
                        function () {
                            newGroupUser.showButtons();
                        }
                    );
                    newGroupUser.user.push(newUser);
                });


                groupViewModel.groupUserCollection.push(newGroupUser);
            });
```

Comment: where is groupUserCollection?

Comment: added the view model that has the arrays

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding in a custom bind to the data-bind on the hidden input and it worked.  But now my subscription dosent work when I add values or remove them.
Code that worked:

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.customMultiBind = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(bindingContext.$data.user(), function (data) {
            if (element.value === "")
            {
                element.value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id)
            }
            else {
                element.value = element.value + "," + ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id)

            }
        });

    }
};
```